ffmpeg - output includes combined video stream from inputs but also exact video streams from inputs
Hi I'm using ffmpeg to transcode some video files from prores or dv to h264/mov. Also I want to add a logo on it and make some other changes. The command line I use is
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i logo.png -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 18 -map 0:a? -map 0:v -filter_complex "yadif,[1]scale=iw*1:-1[wm];[0:v:0][wm]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -disposition:v:0 default output_h264.mov

(Please ignore the 100% scale in the command line. It's a dynamic scale control by the parent python script.)
And the outcome has three video streams. One for the logo,one for the video with logo which is what I want only, and one for original video.
Though I put the default video stream as the one with both video and logo as you can see for -disposition:v:0 default, and it's also playing that stream on the local. But when I tried to upload it on Vimeo or YouTube, it used the wrong stream.
How can I change the command line to let ffmpeg only outputs that
combined video stream? Thanks!

What does ffprobe output_h264.mov say?

Hi, it shows the logo stream is the first stream (tell from the resolution), the second and fourth streams are the clean video and video with logo, and the third one is the audio stream. But I realised the 2nd and 4th streams have very similar data 'Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/bt709, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 4026 kb/s (this one is different), 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn' and they are different from the original input which is a prores.

Try removing the -map 0:v, and make sure that yadif filter has defined input and output... And that the output of yadif is the input of overlay.

Based on the output, the first two streams are video, the third is audio and the fourth is the video stream you want to keep? This keeps the fourth stream (third video stream) and the first, and only, audio stream.
You can use:
ffmpeg -i output_h264.mov -map 0:v:3 -map 0:a:0 -c copy -movflags +faststart output_track_3-4.mov

That should give you the necessary streams only.
